# can anyone help me with this error on Android Studio with JNI is there somethins missing?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface, native

there are my code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
    Mat mRgba, mGray, imgGray, imgCanny;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("MyOpencvLibs");
    }


    BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS:
                    javaCameraView.enableView();
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;
            }


        }

    };

    static {
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV Berhasil Terproses");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV Tidak Berhasil Terproses");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
        javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (javaCameraView != null)
            javaCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (javaCameraView != null)
            javaCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV Berhasil Terproses");
            mLoaderCallBack.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV Tidak Berhasil Terproses");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallBack);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        imgGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        imgCanny = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {

        mRgba.release();
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        OpencvNativeClass.convertGray(mRgba.getNativeObjAddr(), mGray.getNativeObjAddr());

        return mGray;
    }

}
```

OpenNativeClass.java

```
package com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus;

/**
 * Created by Jaws on 6/24/2017.
 */

public class OpencvNativeClass {
    public native static int convertGray(long matAddrRgba, long matAddrGray);
}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    #opencv
    OPENCVROOT:= D:\Download\Compressed\OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk
    OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
    OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
    OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
    include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_danielpanda_agnitiovultus_OpencvNativeClass.cpp

    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
    LOCAL_MODULE := MyOpencvLibs


    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

com_danielpanda_agnitiovultus_OpencvNativeClass.cpp

```
#include "com_danielpanda_agnitiovultus_OpencvNativeClass.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_danielpanda_agnitiovultus_OpencvNativeClass_convertGray
        (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong addrRgba, jlong addrGray) {
    Mat& mRgba = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
    Mat& mGray = *(Mat*)addrGray;

    int conv;
    jint retVal;
    conv = toGray(mRgba, mGray);

    retVal = (jint)conv;

    return retVal;
}

int toGray(Mat img, Mat& gray){
    cvtColor(img, gray, CV_RGBA2GRAY);
    if (gray.rows==img.rows && gray.cols==img.cols)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

com_danielpanda_agnitiovultus_OpencvNativeClass.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
/* Header for class com_danielpanda_agnitiovultus_OpencvNativeClass */

#ifndef _Included_com_danielpanda_agnitiovultus_OpencvNativeClass
#define _Included_com_danielpanda_agnitiovultus_OpencvNativeClass
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_danielpanda_agnitiovultus_OpencvNativeClass
 * Method:    convertGray
 * Signature: (JJ)I
 */
int toGray(Mat img, Mat& gray);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_danielpanda_agnitiovultus_OpencvNativeClass_convertGray
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong, jlong);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a","x86"
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        commandLine "C:/Users/Jaws/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
                'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary249')
}
```

and this is my error log, please help me TwT

```
06-25 11:42:44.085 2656-2656/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-25 11:42:44.097 2656-2656/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-25 11:42:44.113 2656-2656/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
06-25 11:42:44.177 685-704/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus/.MainActivity} from uid 0 on display 0
06-25 11:42:44.181 2656-2656/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-25 11:42:44.189 2656-2661/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
06-25 11:42:44.195 2669-2669/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10059: Read-only file system
06-25 11:42:44.195 2669-2669/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
06-25 11:42:44.196 2669-2669/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-25 11:42:44.198 685-1304/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus for activity com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus/.MainActivity: pid=2669 uid=10059 gids={50059, 9997} abi=x86
06-25 11:42:44.841 2669-2669/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-25 11:42:45.012 2669-2669/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-25 11:42:45.012 2669-2669/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus, PID: 2669
                                                                             java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libMyOpencvLibs.so"
                                                                                 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
                                                                                 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
                                                                                 at com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
06-25 11:42:45.050 685-704/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus/.MainActivity

                                                             [ 06-25 11:42:45.544   685:  704 D/         ]
                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdeb72520, tid 704
06-25 11:42:45.566 670-670/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 670: eglCreateSyncKHR(1181): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

Comment: Instead of **build.gradle**, you posted the manifest, please fix that

Comment: oohh thanks, sorry i forget that @_@ Alex Cohn

Answer (score 0):

Your **build.gradle** looks as if you have borrowed pieces from different sources and never actually cleaned it up. I tried to delete unnecessary parts, and let us try this small one:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.danielpanda.agnitiovultus"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "src/main/cpp/Android.mk"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

After building your APK, use **Build/Analyze APK** in Android Studio menus to check that the native library does contain the `libs/x86/libMyOpencvLibs.so` file (to run on emulator), and also `libs/armeabi-v7a/libMyOpencvLibs.so` file to run on your phone.